# Continue test after element is not available in while loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web page where I have 5 same class buttons and there are 500 and more pages with the same buttons on every page and I made a while loop to click on all of them.
But eventually at the end where buttons are no longer available I receive exit error code.
How can I make it print for example "No more buttons available" and finish the test.

```
res = 1
while res < 10000:
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn default check check green markAsChecked"]')
    buttons[0].send_keys('\n')
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn default check check green markAsChecked"]')
    buttons[1].send_keys('\n')
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn default check check green markAsChecked"]')
    buttons[2].send_keys('\n')
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn default check check green markAsChecked"]')
    buttons[3].send_keys('\n')
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn default check check green markAsChecked"]')
    buttons[4].send_keys('\n')
    driver.refresh()
    res = res + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `if..else` condition to check the `length of button elements`.If the length of the button more than zero then iterate and do some operation else print `No more buttons available` and break.

```
res = 1
while res < 10000:
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn default check check green markAsChecked"]')
    if len(buttons)>0:
      for idx in range(len(buttons)):
          buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn default check check green markAsChecked"]')
          buttons[idx].send_keys('\n')

      driver.refresh()
      res = res + 1
    else:
        print("No more buttons available")
        break
```

Comment: Not much clear about your use-cases if this is not resolving your problem then please share some more info like url or Html to your original post.

Comment: I know it's not clear for you what exactly I should do but it's a long story so I have to click on hundreds and thousands of buttons everyday. Your script works perfectly! Thanks a lot that was very helpful and definitely learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor your loop to be more efficient and introduce a index variable for your buttons list:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


res = 1

while res < 10000:

    # find buttons list
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn default check check green markAsChecked"]')

    # iterate and send keys to buttons[0], buttons[1], etc..
    for i in range(0,4):
        try:
            buttons[i].send_keys('\n')

            # find buttons again, in case buttons element list goes stale
            buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn default check check green markAsChecked"]')

        except NoSuchElementException: # case: button does not exist
            break

    driver.refresh()
    res = res + 1
```

Now instead of calling `buttons[0].send_keys`, `buttons[1].send_keys`, all the way to `buttons[4]`, we are using a for loop from 0 to 4 to accomplish this, performing `button[i].send_keys`.

Inside the `for` loop, we re-run the call for `buttons = driver.find_elements...` so that we can refresh the button elements in the list. This is to handle a potential `StaleElementReferenceException` that may appear as you iterate through the buttons.

We also wrap `button[i].send_keys` in a `try` / `except` block to catch the `NoSuchElementException` to handle the case where buttons do not exist on the page. The code will `break` out of the `for` loop once buttons are no longer found, and continue executing in the `while` loop.

Something to note -- this will **not** handle the case where there are more or less than **exactly 5** buttons on the page. If the number of buttons is subject to change, we want to use `for button in buttons:` instead of `for i in range(0,4)`. If this is the case, please let me know so that I can refactor my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learned a lot from you. But as you said the last page had less than 5 buttons and number of buttons change everyday, 90% of the time is more or less than 5.